# Async socket server as a producer with workers consuming it

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, python-asyncio, asyncsocket

I started playing with asyncio module, and I was wondering if it is possible to build a tcp server that puts some work to do in a queue in order for some workers to execute it.

I tried merging code from the examples in the python documentation.

```py
import asyncio

async def handle_echo(reader, writer):
    data = await reader.read(100)
    message = data.decode()
    addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')

    print(f"Received {message!r} from {addr!r}")

    print(f"Send: {message!r}")
    writer.write(data)
    await writer.drain()

    print("Close the connection")
    writer.close()

async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(
        handle_echo, '127.0.0.1', 8888)

    addr = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
    print(f'Serving on {addr}')

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(main())
```

and the worker

```py
import asyncio
import random
import time


async def worker(name, queue):
    while True:
        # Get a "work item" out of the queue.
        sleep_for = await queue.get()

        # Sleep for the "sleep_for" seconds.
        await asyncio.sleep(sleep_for)

        # Notify the queue that the "work item" has been processed.
        queue.task_done()

        print(f'{name} has slept for {sleep_for:.2f} seconds')


async def main():
    # Create a queue that we will use to store our "workload".
    queue = asyncio.Queue()

    # Generate random timings and put them into the queue.
    total_sleep_time = 0
    for _ in range(20):
        sleep_for = random.uniform(0.05, 1.0)
        total_sleep_time += sleep_for
        queue.put_nowait(sleep_for)

    # Create three worker tasks to process the queue concurrently.
    tasks = []
    for i in range(3):
        task = asyncio.create_task(worker(f'worker-{i}', queue))
        tasks.append(task)

    # Wait until the queue is fully processed.
    started_at = time.monotonic()
    await queue.join()
    total_slept_for = time.monotonic() - started_at

    # Cancel our worker tasks.
    for task in tasks:
        task.cancel()
    # Wait until all worker tasks are cancelled.
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)

    print('====')
    print(f'3 workers slept in parallel for {total_slept_for:.2f} seconds')
    print(f'total expected sleep time: {total_sleep_time:.2f} seconds')


asyncio.run(main())
```

As soon as I started coding, a lot of questions came to my mind.

Does the server create its own event loop?

Can I serve a server while workers consume jobs from a queue that the server fills.

Is there any good guide for this kind of applications or for guiding people into this mess of new terms that async is bringing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure,
but the issues was with the queue that was creating its own event loop, so I had to create it inside the main async function.
While `start_serving` and `serve_forever` did not make any difference.
I am still trying stuff and studying the documentation, so I will accept this answer for the moment.

```py
from asyncio import Queue, create_task, gather, run, start_server


async def do_work(name: str, broker: Queue):
    while True:
        data = await broker.get()

        print(f'worker `{name}` is consuming {data}')

        broker.task_done()


async def main():
    broker = Queue(maxsize=512)

    async def handler(reader, writer):
        data = await reader.read()
        message = data.decode()
        addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')

        print(f'Received {message!r} from {addr!r}')

        print(f'Send: {message!r}')
        writer.write(data)
        await writer.drain()

        print(f'Add work')
        await broker.put(data)

        print('Close the connection')
        writer.close()

    server = await start_server(handler, '127.0.0.1', 8888)

    addr = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
    print(f'Serving on {addr}')

    # await server.start_serving()

    workers = []
    for i in range(3):
        worker = create_task(do_work(f'worker-{i}', broker))
        workers.append(worker)

    # await gather(*workers)
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(main())
```